# VBA to click web button with dynamic elementID and repetitive class

Tags: html, vba, excel, web-scraping

I am quite new to VBA/html, trying to automate filling a form, but cannot even call it ... I searched the web for **weeks** tried many different code combinations, but none got me there.

The HTML code/element looks like this:

```
div title:"TextText" class:"text-truncate mb-2" id="abc_sidebar_startmenuitem" data-type="record" data-appid="82" data url="index.cfm?Xxx=&Yyy=">

i class="fa icon-app-82 mr-1 fa-fw">/i>

span class="clickable" id="ext-eng123">Text/span>
/div>
```

Problem is that `class="clickable"` is 30th appearance of clickable on the page, `id="ext-eng123"` is built from the text `ext-eng` and 3 variable unknown digits, always different.

Example of VBA code used:

```
Sub GetClick()
    Dim ie As Object
    Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://company.application.com/home/index.cfm?Tab=home"
        Do While .Busy
            DoEvents
        Loop
        Do While .readyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
    End With
    Dim objIE As Object
    objIE = document.getElementByClassName("clickable")(29)
    objIE.Click
End Sub
```

I tried over 10+ different code samples, including calling frame number, none worked, I am stuck.

Comment: *"weeks"?*   Please share some more of what you've tried, and the results.  "None Worked" isn't much help.  Errors?  Where/when/why? What's the data look like, and what do you need it to look like?

Comment: Get the element with id "abc_sidebar_startmenuitem" then call `getElementsByClassName("clickable")` on that element.

Comment: Many thanks for replies.  @Tim: "abc_sidebar_startmenuitem" and getElementsByClassName("clickable") appears on the page in 8 different combinations. it is 8 spans with id "ext-eng-+++" where +++ are 3 numbers, unique for each span, but whenever the page is click they are different. @ ashleedawg I will post som,e examples with err message below. weeks, but not full-time, couple hours every other day :)

Comment: `id` is supposed to be unique on any given page, so that sounds like it's a bit broken.

Comment: Some more examples of codes that didn't work

Comment: Set Elements = Doc.GetElementsByTagName("span")

    For Each Element In Elements
        If Element.Innertext = "Inspection" Then
           .Click

Comment: Set clickButton = HTMLdoc.getElementsByClassName("clickable")(29)
    MsgBox clickButton.outerHTML
    Click.Button.dispatchEvent evtClick

Comment: Tim, ID is unique for each div/span+clickable. but it changes upon every visit. it is always a combination of "ext-eng-" and 3 numbers, like ext-eng-123. "clickable" appears 30 times in the script, of which 8 times with "abc_sidebar_startmenuitem", I need to call 2nd appearance

Answer (score 2):

Try the following code. It is hard to give any solution without playing with that site. They are always hypothetical.

```
Sub GetClick()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, Html As HTMLDocument

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate "https://company.application.com/home/index.cfm?Tab=home"
        While .Busy = True Or .ReadyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set Html = .Document
    End With

    ''If the problem still persists, make sure to put here some delay

    Html.querySelector(".clickable[id^='ext-eng']").Click
End Sub
```

Another approach might be something like (if the word "Text" didn't appear anywhere with the same class name):

```
For Each elem In Html.getElementsByClassName("clickable")
    If InStr(elem.innerText, "Text") > 0 Then elem.Click: Exit For
Next elem
```

Reference to add:

```
Microsoft Internet Controls
Microsoft HTML Object Library
```

Comment: Thank you SIM, but getting Run-time err 91. Obj or var not set. the "clickable" with "ext-eng" repeats 8 times on the page, mine is 2nd.

Comment: What about this `Html.querySelector("#abc_sidebar_startmenuitem span.clickable").Click`. Tim Williams has already suggested this. You have given us a very minor portion of html elements to provide you with a solution let alone they are badly formatted, i meant no close tags.

Comment: Same Sim. I know, my bad, but couldnt figure out how to post it completely given the rules for posting. Added image above if that could help...

Comment: Okay, let us try in some different ways. What is it written on that button. Is it the word `Text`? If it is just check if there is any other button with the same name `Text`.

Comment: If it breaks, there are still few ways to go. Just check if there is anything, i meant anything uniquely used here that has not been used elsewhere such as `data-type="record"`.

Comment: SIM, it works!  The only problem is that with Html.querySelector("#gsw_sidebar_startmenuitem span.clickable").Click . I get to 1st of 8 start menu items, while I need to get the 2nd. I tried  Html.querySelector("#gsw_sidebar_startmenuitem span.clickable")(1). Click but that didn't work. Thanks a lot anyway.

Comment: The right try should be `Html.querySelectorAll("#gsw_sidebar_startmenuitem span.clickable")(1).Click`

Comment: Hi SIM, both these options work (Html.querySelectorAll as well as If InStr(elem.innerText, "Text"), thanks a million! :)