# VBA to html, onclick event function with dynamic element attributes

Tags: html, excel, vba, onclick, dynamic-attributes

I am trying to automate filling in a web form on intracompany web in excel using IE. My previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50751921/vba-to-click-web-button-with-dynamic-elementid-and-repetitive-class) was to target dynamic element ID which got resolved thank to
[SIM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9189799/sim) (thanks again!)
Unfortunately I cannot use the same method to proceed; with the code below I can open the url and click the dynamic element, which opens new window but there I have no luck identifying attributes/elements to click.

```
Sub Route4b()
Dim ie As New InternetExplorer, Html As HTMLDocument
With ie
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "https://company.application.com/home/index.cfm?Tab=home"
    While .Busy = True Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
    Set Html = .document
End With
For Each elem In Html.getElementsByClassName("clickable")
If InStr(elem.innerText, "Inspection") > 0 Then elem.Click: Exit For
Next elem
While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Wend
For Each elem In Html.getElementsByClassName("inspection-font clickable")
If InStr(elem.innerText, "EU KSR - Dock") > 0 Then elem.Click: Exit For
Next elem
While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Wend
End Sub
```

The code runs without error message, it just doesnt execute the 2nd innertext click.

Below also html code, the only unique attributes are span title and Innertext, with span class shared for a number of different 'span titles' (say 10).

### Dynamic link

```
    <input name="tblheaderupcoming" id="tblheaderupcoming" type="hidden" value="["","Checklist","Assigned To","Due Date","Frequency",""]"/>
    <div class="card table-card data-table mb-0">
     <div class="card-header bg-secondary pointer rendered-toggle card-status card-status-upcoming" aria-expanded="true" href="#cardupcoming" data-togle="collapse" data-id="upcoming" data-priority="2">...</div>
     <div class="card-block dashboard-container collapse show" id="cardupcoming" aria-expanded="true">...</div>
      <div class="dataTables_wrapper dt-bootstrap4 no-footer" id="tableupcoming_wrapper">
       <div class="col-xs-6 px-2">...</div>
       <div class="col-xs-6 px-2">...</div>
       <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped no-more-tables table-upcoming dataTable no-footer rendered-nmt" id="tableupcoming" role="grid" aria-describedby="tableupcoming_info">...</table>
        <thead>
         <tr class="bg-active" role="row">...</tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
         <tr class="odd" role="row">
          <td data/title=" "></td>
          <td data-title="Checklist">
           <div>
            <span title="EU KSR - Dock Audit Type:OPS Calibration - KSR" class="inspection-font clickable" onclick="window.open('goto_pit.cfm?samid=3053960&siteid=882&thestatus=upcoming');">EU KSR - Dock</span>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated, I search as much as I could but didn't find anything I could apply. And apologizing for a disability to express it in somewhat clearer way, I am amateur at best. Many thanks!

Comment: don't automate IE, its full of bugs and doesn't report ready state correctly. better use HTTP Request.